# Creating folders at the different end directories

Tags: python, python-os

There are photos and videos in all 2nd_layers folders, I would like to create photos and videos folders in all 2nd_layers folders and categorize those photos & videos.

**Expected output**

```
root_path
┃
┣━1st_layer_A
┃    ┣━2nd_layer_A
┃    ┃    ┣━Create_New_Photos_Folder_1
┃    ┃    ┣━Create_New_Videos_Folder_1
┃    ┃
┃    ┣━2nd_layer_B
┃         ┣━Create_New_Photos_Folder_2
┃         ┣━Create_New_Videos_Folder_2
┃
┣━1st_layer_B
     ┣━2nd_layer_C
     ┃    ┣━Create_New_Photos_Folder_3
     ┃    ┣━Create_New_Videos_Folder_3
     ┃
     ┣━2nd_layer_D
          ┣━Create_New_Photos_Folder_4
          ┣━Create_New_Videos_Folder_4
```

The code I tried to create folders

```
import os

path = 'root_path'

for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(path):
    for subdirectory in subdirectories:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(root, subdirectory) + '\\Photos')
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(root, subdirectory) + '\\Videos')
```

However, when running the above code, it will be a infinite loop, seems like creating a lot of folders. How should I modify the above code to achieve the expected results?

Also how can I search through files in all 2nd_layer folders and move them into corresponding photos/videos folders? I have some drafts on that.

```
import os
import shutil

for file in 2nd_layer:
    if file.endswith(".mp4"):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(2nd_layer_folder_path, file), os.path.join(2nd_layer_video_folder_path,file))

    if file.endswith(".jpg"):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(2nd_layer_folder_path , file), os.path.join(2nd_layer_photos_folder_path,file))
```

Is it possible to create folders and move files at the same time by combining the above codes?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import shutil

path = "root_path"

depth = 1

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    if root[len(path):].count(os.sep) >= depth:
        print(root)
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(root) + '\\Photos')
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(root) + '\\Videos')
        except:
            continue
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".mp4"):
                shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(os.path.join(root) + '\\Videos', file))
            if file.endswith(".jpg"):
                shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(os.path.join(root) + '\\Photos', file))
```

Reference:
https://newbedev.com/python-os-walk-to-certain-level

Comment: I tested this and it works well, but I'm wondering: why does it create extra empty "Photo" and "Video" folders in the "1rst_layer" folders? You said in your question that you needed "to create photos and videos folders in all 2nd_layers folders". How would you make it so that it *only* creates "Photo" and "Video" folders in the "2nd_layer" folders, and not in the "1rst_layer" folders?

Comment: When I use the above code, it doesn't create extra "Photos" and "Video" folders in the 1st_layer folders. I am wondering why we got the different results when we use the same code.

Comment: Interesting. Judging by the double backslash `\\ ` in your paths, your system is a Windows, right? I used a Linux (Ubuntu, specifically), so I had to change the `\\ ` to `/`. I also specified the specific path for the `path` variable: "/home/user/test", a folder I created to test this program. These were the only changes to your code.

Comment: In case you were wondering *how* I tested your code: inside "test", I created two folders: "1rst_layer_A" and "1rst_layer_B". Inside each of those folders, I created two folders: the "2nd_layer" folders as specified in your question. I then put six image files and six video files inside each of the "2nd_layer" folders, and ran your program. The program was *not* inside the "test" folder; it was elsewhere. I'm assuming that I tested it under the conditions you specified? If not, let me know.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows 10. The conditions are also correct. However, I want to ask where you point the "path". In your case, did you assign "test" as your "path"?

Comment: I put `path = "/home/user/test"` instead of `path = "root_path"`.

Comment: Then it should be same as mine. I don't have a clue then. Thanks for your sharing tho.